# QGIS SAGA split lines at points creates redundant lines

Tags: qgis, point, splitting, linestring

I have 2 projected (ESPG 2039) layers of roads and points (bus stops and junctions). I snapped the points to the roads layer and this is how it looks:
[image: roads and points]

I then try yo use Saga Split lines by points to split the lines but I get redundant lines, e.g. the green and brown lines in the middle of the picture:
[image: redundant lines]

Some of the redundant lines are totally independent and some are part of valid lines. I tried using different epsilon values: 0, 0.001, 0.1, 1, 5 and 10.
0.1 gave the least redundant lines, but still many exist.

Is there a way to prevent the creation of these redundant lines?
Sample data (ESPG 2039) can be found here:  https://www.filedropper.com/roadsandpoints

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have to use the SAGA split and you don't need the data:
1. Dissolve all the lines
2. Use the split plugin

When I tried this method, I received the expected results (though with 1 extra line that is easy to delete).

EDIT: Use spatial join to retrieve the original layer attributes, if needed